# Difference between logical implication and AND and when to use what

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, self-learning, predicate-logic

**I am confused between logical implication and local and. When to use what.** Logically i can make sense on which to use but intuitively i am not able to. For ex.,

**Not All that glitters is gold**

**Diagrametric representation: Glitters set is disjoint with gold set**

It can be expressed as $\neg \forall x \{ glitters(x) \implies gold(x)\} \equiv \exists x \{ glitters(x) \land  \neg gold(x)\}$

But if i think 2 disjoint sets. I think i can write it as $\forall x \{ glitters(x) \land \neg gold(x) \}$ or $\exists x \{ glitters(x) \land \neg gold(x) \}$  or $\forall x \{ \neg glitters(x) \land  gold(x) \}$ or $\exists x \{ \neg glitters(x) \land  gold(x) \}$ . But if i use logical implication formulae , these seem to be wrong. But the above representations look like 2 disjoint sets right? I am not able to grasp the differences between the above.

Comment: You're diagrametric needs revision. "Not all that glitters is gold" just says there are things that glitter which are not gold. This doesn't imply the sets are disjoint. *Some* glittering things could still be gold, just not all glittering things.

Comment: "not all glitters is gold" states that the set of glitters is not a subset of the set of gold. But it does not state that the sets are disjoint.

Comment: understood sir, thank you